# MySQL: Link answers to comments, grouped and limited

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following MySQL table:

```
 +----+--------+------+
 | id | answer | type |
 +----+--------+------+
>| 1  | -1     | 1    |
 | 2  |  1     | 2    |
 | 3  |  1     | 1    |
>| 4  | -1     | 2    |
 | 5  |  4     | 2    |
 | 6  |  4     | 1    |
>| 7  | -1     | 1    |
 | 8  |  7     | 2    |
>| 9  | -1     | 2    |
>| 10 | -1     | 1    |
>| 11 | -1     | 2    |
 +----+--------+------+
 > = original comment
```

- The entries with answer = -1 are the original comments.
- The entries with answer != -1 are answers to the comment with the respective id.
- Furthermore there are types of comments (in this case 1 or 2).

Now I want to retrieve the original comments (for a specified type and a specified limit) and their answers (type and limit do not matter). Further it would be great to group the result by the two types (again, only the original comment's type matters for grouping).

A query result for type=1 and limit=2 should look like that (not grouped yet):

```
 +----+--------+------+
 | id | answer | type |
 +----+--------+------+
>| 1  | -1     | 1    |
 | 2  |  1     | 2    |
 | 3  |  1     | 1    |
>| 7  | -1     | 1    |
 | 8  |  7     | 2    |
 +----+--------+------+
```

I have tried several kinds of queries for hours now, can I implement it without a procedure? What would the procedure look like?

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: can you also provide a desired output given a type and limit?

Comment: Okay, I did and added some entries in the table.

Comment: By convention, we use NULL, not -1, to represent orphans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get 2 original comments of type-1 first, then join the table again to get both original comments and responses.

```
select b.*
from (
  select id
  from answers
  where type = 1 and answer = -1
  limit 2) a
join answers b on a.id = b.id or a.id = b.answer;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c7e9/2)

To select 2 original comments of each type, you'll need to use user-defined-variable to index each original comment. The following code indexes the first original comment as 1, the second one as 2, and so on, then resets to 1 when the type changes. Finally in the final where statement filter out indices greater than 2.

```
select b.*, a.idx
from (
  select id, @idx:=if(@type=a.type,@idx+1,1) idx, @type:=a.type
  from (select id, type from answers2 where answer is null order by type) a
  join (select @type:=null, @idx:=null) b) a
join answers2 b on a.id = b.id or a.id = b.answer
where a.idx <= 2;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f8192/12)

Comment: Nice, that works. And how would I do it to retrieve the first two records of each type without delivering a type?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! And even so short code. Nice. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, on my local MySQL server the indexing does not work properly. Almost all records get idx=1, I think it has to do with the issue about user-defined variables explained on this pages: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html. The fix with "force index(type)" does not work for me.

Comment: @phogl, can you create a fiddle to replicate this problem?

Comment: You can see it when you add "select b.*, idx".

Comment: @phogl, thanks for the fiddle. after ordering the view by type first, then apply idx, it now works. see updated answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, now it works. Thank you again! :) Btw, it would be good to rename "answers2" back to "answer" and "answer is null" back to "answer = -1" for other readers using the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a separate column or even a different table if you are worried about too much data duplication. You are overthinking it.

Comment: Okay right, I could put comments and answers in two different tables and add the parent's type as column to the answer table. Have not thought about that yet. Thanks!